# Using userId in cookie generated by oAuth dance as the Id for users of my application

Tags: cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0, hyperledger-composer

I followed this tutorial. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out

Once I authenticate with Github I get a cookie that has a key called "userId". 
Is it a good practice to use that key as the Id of a participant ?

That way I can sign up users in my backend easily via Github.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a Participant as an actor in a business network. A participant might be an individual in an organization or it can be a role depending on the requirement (with multiple identities mapped to it but which are trackable nonetheless). A participant has an issued (or indeed already existing) identity mapped to it in the business network (you've seen how certificates are issued by an Org's CA etc).

As for good practice - the question whether it compromises anything, by using the user ID as a participant identifier or other field in its class (ie does it reveal anything to others on the business network, eg from other Organisations in the business network, that they should not know). You would be the best judge of that (and others here may add to this), but it sounds like it may be an approach that works for you.

Comment: thanks. Is it guaranteed that that userId doesn't change over time ? I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: yes, the userid that you issued in the business network, remains the same. see example here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue - the identity (in the business network) and is mapped to a participant (in a participant class and with a participant name of your choosing) - the identities are stored in a system registry called the IdentityRegistry. The identity registry contains a set of mappings from identities (digital certificates) to participants. Business network cards contain that identity (digital certificate) that is mapped to a participant.

Comment: Note that you can see a list of identities (fingerprint hash and identity name, as well as which participant its mapped to) using the command - `composer identity list -c admin@basic-sample-network` (example)

Comment: is that userId generated by composer ? Or is it generated by oAuth ? I have no idea where that key comes from hence my apprehension to use it as a key for my participants...

Comment: you supply the userId when issuing an identity in Composer - see example here (CLI-based and JS based) https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.identity.issue.html - if you're referring to what you see in the `identity list`  the field `identityId:` is generated by Composer